# Help With Uv Unwrapping Sword

Tags: uv

so I have some experience with Blender but I always have troubles unwrapping. I use UV Packmaster and TexTools. It seems the issues always come when using the Subsurface Modifier. Anywho I am curious how I fix this edge stretching.

And get these UVs looking right. For what I can see I feel the topology is decent and my edge seems are where they should be, yet it still stretches where the subsurface curves. Maybe I need to use bevel modifier on the guard to get the curved edges I want? Any help would be great.

In the 4th image you can see it looks fine, I am not sure why others aren't.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: As you can see with this image, this is not stretching at all it looks perfect.]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you show the creases more clearly?

Comment: Adding more photos